# Are Merkaba and Sri Yantra the same thing?

Tags: other-religions, terminology, sri-vidya

I was reading an article about **[Merkaba](http://edenisnow.com/what-is-your-merkaba-and-how-do-you-activate-it/)** and it says:

> A merkaba is a star tetrahedron, a three dimensional 8 pointed star
>   made from two triangular pyramids, one pointing up and the other down.
>   The male pyramid points upwards and begins at your knees, extending
>   several feet above your head. The female pyramid extends downwards
>   from your shoulders and reaches several feet below your own feet.

My question: Is this the same thing that we refer to as Sri Yantra?

Comment: Can you link to the article?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have updated the link. Thanks for pointing it out.